# Data not sending through with AJAX call

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am having difficulties with an AJAX call. I am trying to send over the id of the user who is making the announcement and then the message. For some reason the user_id is not sending over. The message is sending over, but I am getting an error saying it has an undefined index, but I process all of the contents into another file and the message is going through. I am trying to use a session of the user's id for that to send through, but I have also tried doing a `SELECT` query and sending it that way and it still doesn't send.

Here is my session code..

```
$userid = ( isset( $_SESSION['user'] ) ? $_SESSION['user'] : "" );
```

What am I doing wrong that is making the userid not send through and for my query to not send to my database?

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
             $("#submit_announcement").on("click", function () {

             var user_message = $("#announcement_message").val();
                $user = this.value;
                $.ajax({ 
                    url: "insert_announcements.php", 
                    type: "POST",
                    //data : 
                    //{'message':message,'anothermessgae':another}
                    data: {
                           "user_id": $user,
                                        "message": user_message
                            },
                    success: function (data) {
                           //  console.log(data); // data object will return the response when status code is 200
                             if (data == "Error!") {
                                 alert("Unable to get user info!");
                                 alert(data);
                             } else {
                                 $(".announcement_success").fadeIn();
                                 $(".announcement_success").show();
                                 $('.announcement_success').html('Payment Status Changed!');
                                 $('.announcement_success').delay(5000).fadeOut(400);
                             }
                         },
                         error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                             alert(textStatus + "|" + errorThrown);
                             //console.log("error"); //otherwise error if status code is other than 200.
                         }
                     });
                 });
             });
```

Form

```
  <div class="announcement_success"></div>
        <p>Add New Announcement</p>
            <form action="" method="POST" id="insert_announcements">
            <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $userid; ?>" id="approved_id" name="user_id" />
                <textarea rows="4" cols="50" id="announcement_message" name="message" class="inputbarmessage" placeholder="Message" required></textarea>
                <label for="contactButton">
                    <button type="button" class="contactButton" id="submit_announcement">Add Announcement</button>
                </label>
            </form>
```

insertannouncements.php

```
$announcement_user_id= $_POST['user_id'];
$announcement_message= $_POST['user_message'];
//$test = print_r($_POST, true); 
//file_put_contents('test.txt', $test); 
//var_dump($announcement_user_id);

$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "", "", "");
$stmt2 = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO announcements (user_id, message, date) VALUES (?, ?, NOW())");
    if ( !$stmt2 || $con->error ) {
        // Check Errors for prepare
         die('Announcement INSERT prepare() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($con->error));
    }
    if(!$stmt2->bind_param('is', $announcement_user_id, $announcement_message)) {
        // Check errors for binding parameters
        die('Announcement INSERT bind_param() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($stmt2->error));
    }
    if(!$stmt2->execute()) {
        die('Announcement INSERT execute() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($stmt2->error));
    }
        //echo "Announcement was added successfully!";
    else
    {
         echo "Announcement Failed!";
    }
?>
```

I get the following error

```
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: user_message in <b>/home4/gregre/public_html/example.com/insert_announcements.php</b> on line <b>9</b><br />
```

Announcement INSERT execute() failed: Column 'message' cannot be null

But I am sending the content of what is sent over to my file and the message is sending through? Just the user_id is showing blank.

Comment: At least `$_POST['user_message'];` is wrong, the property is named `message`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few mistakes:

1. `$user = $("#approved_id").val();`
2. `"user_message": user_message`

Comment: Awesome this worked. Why when I click on insert_announcements from the network tab does it say. "Announcement Failed!" But everything is sending through?

Comment: @Becky - Because `$_POST['user_message']` is null, you haven't sent anything like that, it's either `$_POST['message']` or you change the property in the ajax data object.

Comment: Ah... Lemme have a look. What do you get as the response? Check in both Console and the REST API... @Becky...

Comment: @Becky Try giving it as `$_POST["message"]` instead of `$_POST["user_message"]`?

Comment: I changed it to what you said and it works and sends to my db, just the network response is saying failed. In my test.txt file I get the correct contents as well...`Array
(
    [user_id] => 1
    [user_message] => Welcome everyone!
)`

Comment: Am I missing something @adeneo?

Comment: @PraveenKumar Seems fine. Someone just got 125 reputation I guess ;)

Comment: LoL... That could be me! `:P`

Answer (score 0):

```
data: {
   "user_id": $user,
   "user_message": user_message
 },
```

Change to `user_message`

Answer (score 0):

With: `$user = this.value;`

you are trying to get the value of the clicked element (the submit button).

It should be: `$user = $("#approved_id").val();`

Also check the name of the `message` variable, either rename it 'user_message' on the js/client side:

```
"user_message": user_message
```

**or** 'message' on the php/server side.

```
$announcement_message= $_POST['message'];
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the issue I am seeing:

In your AJAX call you are sending these parameters:

```
data: {
  "user_id": $user,
  "message": user_message
},
```

Where `$user` is defined like this: `$user = this.value;` which means the value comes from the the function it resides in which is the `click` event on `"#submit_announcement"`like this:

```
$("#submit_announcement").on("click", function () {
    //..code
    $user = this.value;
    //..code
});
```

Doing it this way you are assigning the value of the element `#submit_announcement` to `$user` however if we look at the HTML, we see that `#submit_announcement` is just a simple button with no value:

```
<button type="button" class="contactButton" id="submit_announcement">Add Announcement</button>
```

What it seems you are trying to do is get values submitted by the form. To do that you need to use the event handler `.submit()` rather then `.click()` since you are submitting a `form`. The `submit()` event should be attached to the form element like this:

```
$("#insert_announcements").submit(function () {
    //..code
});
```

Also make sure you change your `button` element's type attribute to `submit` like this:

```
<button type="submit" class="contactButton" id="submit_announcement">Add Announcement</button>
```

Once you do that, now you can use `.serialize()` to encode your form elements and values to a string form that can be sent in your POST request like this:

```
$("#insert_announcements").submit(function () {
    var form_elems = $(this).serialize();
});
```

Now that you have all that, you can send it through ajax, thus

**FINAL RESULT:**

```
$("#insert_announcements").submit(function () {
    var form_elems = $(this).serialize();
    $.ajax({ 
         url: "insert_announcements.php", 
         type: "POST",
         data: form_elems,
         success: function (data) {
             //your result code
         }
    });
    return false;
});
```